# Error creating SSL certificate in GCP: Domain name longer than 64 bytes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create an SSL certificate in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) from Google Cloud Console. However, I am encountering an error message that says:

```
Invalid value for field 'resource.managed.domains[0]': 'www.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk.com'. Domain names longer than 64 bytes are not supported at index 0.
```

[image]

I understand that this error message is indicating that my domain name is longer than 64 bytes, which is the maximum length allowed for domain names in GCP. However, I need to use a domain name that is longer than 64 bytes for my application.

How can I create an SSL certificate in GCP for a domain name that is longer than 64 bytes? Is there a workaround or alternative solution that I can use to achieve this?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot. First, you do not want long domain names. Over 64 bytes is not supported by many clients, systems, etc. You will have intermittent problems and failures. Second, you cannot use Google Cloud managed services if the name is longer than 64 characters. **Hostnames used for server TLS/SSL certificates should not exceed 64 bytes as a fully qualified domain name**.